# Can't get MySQL/MariaDB to work with Django 1.10.1 and Python 3.5 on Fedora 24?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, mariadb, fedora

Besides the above, I'm using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. MariaDB server 10.1.17 was installed via `dnf install`

I'm working through the first Django tutorial. My runserver command:

```
(djTut3)$ python manage.py runserver
```

ran OK, with a warning about migration.

In part 2, here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

I ran:

```
(djTut3)$ python manage.py migrate
```

as instructed, and got the following errors:

```
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I did a lot of searching, and tried the below (among other things), mostly from SO:

===

```
$ sudo dnf install MySQL-python
<No error>

$ python3 manage.py migrate
<Same errors as before>

$ sudo dnf install mariadb-devel
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade)

$ sudo dnf install mariadb-devel --best --allowerasing
<No error>

$ python3 manage.py migrate
<Same errors as before>

$ pip3 install mysql-python
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

$ pip3 install mysql-connector
<No error>

$ pip3 install mysql-client
_mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

$sudo dnf install python-devel mysql-devel
<already installed>
```

===

Now I still can't get

```
(djTut3)$ python manage.py migrate
```

to work, and

```
(djTut3)$ python manage.py runserver
```

gives *the same error* as the migrate command.

My settings.py includes:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djTut3',
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer some help with this?

Thanks very much in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should install Python packages via `pip`, not your OS package manager. MySQLdb is not available for Python 3, as you can see from the error when you tried via `pip3`.

The reason you had issues installing mysql-client is presumably because you need the python-devel package, or whatever the Fedora equivalent is; that would be a dnf install.

However since you did succeed with mysql-connector, you can use that; you need to configure Django to use it as shown in [that library's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html), by replacing `'django.db.backends.mysql'` with `'mysql.connector.django'`.

Comment: I replaced 'django.db.backends.mysql' with 'mysql.connector.django' in my settings file; now `python manage.py runserver` works. But though `python manage.py migrate` runs, it produces the errors:
`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1`
A search on this new issue yielded a suggestion to undo the settings change, which wasn't helpful. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: On re-running `python manage.py migrate` I now get the errors:
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1050 (42S01): Table 'django_content_type' already exists
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'django_content_type' already exists`